# Some big-theta and big-omega notation question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science

> Let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $f ( n ) = n ^ { 2 } + \sqrt { n }$. Determine whether the following statement is true or false, providing a proof for your answer.

> $ f(n) = \Theta(n^2) $

> $ \log_2[f(n)] = \Theta(\log_2n) $

> $ 2^{f(n)} = \Theta(2{n^2}) $

> $2 ^ { 2 ^ { f ( n ) } } = \Omega ( g )$, where $g(1) = 1$, $g(2) = 2$, and $g(n) = [g(n - 1)] ^2 + [g(n - 2)] ^2$ for $n \ge 3$.

How can I get a prove to determine the abovementioned is true or false

for a),

what I have got for the first questionnow is:

> I have $ c_1, c_2 , n_0 > 0$

> c_1 $ \leq  n^2 + \sqrt(n) \leq c_2 $

> c_1 $ \leq  1 + \frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}} \leq c_2 $

So how can I continue to prove the Big theta notation? I don't understand how to choose the c

Comment: Use for instance $n>1\implies n^4>n^2>n$ now take square root to get $0<\sqrt{n}<n^2$ do you see $c_1$ and $c_2$ now ? The other questions are similar.

Comment: I understand that when n > 1 them $ n^4$ grow faster than $n^2 $ also grow faster than $ n$ 
but I don't understand the sqrt part. Can you explain more please.

Comment: $\sqrt$ is an increasing function so $n^4>n\implies\sqrt{n^4}>\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: therefore c1 should be 1 and c2 should be 2?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will set you on the right track
$$c_1 n^2\le n^2+\sqrt{n}\le c_2 n^2$$
Now just find $c_1$ and $c_2$, both greater than zero, that makes the inequality true as $n$ increases past some $n_0$. Once you achieve this, then you can say
$$n^2+\sqrt{n}\in\Theta\left(n^2\right)$$
The same strategy applies to the other Big Theta problems.